# Consume me with tonic

Tags: riddle, word

> Consume me with tonic, a real superhero,
>   along with a parent and child in a trio.
>   Opposite letter to those stuck in bureau;
>   when lacking in me, you may feel like a zero.

What am I?

Hint:

> Insteady of tonic, orange juice works as well. So does cola.

Comment: Sounds like friends or couples

Comment: You don't consume your friends with tonic. You'd need some fava beans and a nice chianti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Spirit

Consume me with tonic, a real superhero,

> Spirits are hard alcoholic drinks such as gin or vodka which are usually mixed with a soft drink when consumed.

along with a parent and child in a trio.

> The Father, the Son and the Holy **Spirit**

Opposite letter to those stuck in bureau;

> Could be referring to the the oppostion between the *"letter of the law"* and the *"spirit of the law"*, an [idiomatic antithesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law).

when lacking in me, you may feel like a zero.

> Your spirit can also refer to the quality of your mood, so if you're lacking in spirit you won't feel very self-confident.